# The SettingsFlyout can not be displayed in Windows Phone 10

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I created a custom SettingsFlyout. The SettingsFlyout appears properly when it runs in my Desktop. But when I run it on a mobile device, the SettingsFlyout does not appear. Here is the code:

```
  private void SettingsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
       var flyout = new TestSettingsFlyout();
       flyout.Show();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remarks at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.settingsflyout.aspx) stands:

> Caution  SettingsFlyout is not supported for use in UWP apps for Windows 10.
>
> Caution  SettingsFlyout is supported only for use with the SettingsPane in Windows 8. While the SettingsFlyout type is visible in Windows Phone projects, SettingsPane is not present on Windows Phone, so use of SettingsFlyout is not supported.

Therefore this may be the problem.